# MacBook Air Early 2014 responds to SMC reset but doesn't turn on

Tags: macbook-pro

MacBook responds to Shift+Control+Option+Power button, the magsafe's light color changes from orange color to green momentarily then goes back to orange. So it means the MacBook is still alive.

What could be the possible cause why the machine won't turn on?

**UPDATE**

It's working again now, after letting it rest for about two weeks since it crashed.

While in the middle of booting (progress bar is not finished) the computer just turns itself off. Tried to turn it on again it just kept on turning itself off while booting.

This permanently fix the boot crashing: https://discussions.apple.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-29433214-653435/image.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You probably have defective hardware. The SMC appears to work, so it's simply not allowing power-on due to a problem elsewhere in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The DC in board in any Mac is a little computer in and of itself. It's a little more complicated than the computer (processor/controller) that's embedded in a lightning cable / thunderbolt cable / your MagSafe charging cable but less complicated than the computer in your power adapter.

The light going orange means that the charge board doesn't sense a fully charged battery. That's all that's really alive - so you would need to have a technician to take apart your computer to isolate why it's not starting.

Unless you want to take on that role - the best advice would be to run through the normal steps when a computer will not start.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204267